# Why is "self" Blocking Data from CloudKit in my QueryOperation

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, cloudkit

I have multiple CKRecords in my database in Cloudkit. I turn those CKRecords into annotations for my map. Ever since I had to add `self` before my variable `var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()` in my queryoperation, it has only been loading one annotation to my Map. Why is that and how do I fix that??? Any help would be amazing!

How I fetch the records -

```
 var points: [MKPointAnnotation] = []
 var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
 let database = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase

 func fetchTruck() {

let truePredicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
let eventQuery = CKQuery(recordType: "User", predicate: truePredicate)
let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: eventQuery)


queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = {  (record) in



    self.points.append(self.annotation)

    self.annotation.title = record["username"] as? String
    self.annotation.subtitle = record["hours"] as? String
    if let location = record["location"] as? CLLocation {
        self.annotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
    }

    print("recordFetchedBlock: \(record)")

    self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.annotation)

    }




        self.database.add(queryOperation)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing in more detail your code I think that the problem is that you are using always the same annotation. MKPointAnnotation is a class, a reference value, that means that every time you assing a value to self.annotation you're changing the reference, not creating a new one.

You're modifiying your app UI (mapView) inside the `CKQueryOperation` closure. Try to run the *modification* code in the main thread

Try something like...

```
var points: [MKPointAnnotation] = []
let database = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase

func fetchTruck() 
{
    let truePredicate = NSPredicate(value: true)

    let eventQuery = CKQuery(recordType: "User", predicate: truePredicate)
    let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: eventQuery)

    queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = {  (record) in
        var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

        annotation.title = record["username"] as? String
        annotation.subtitle = record["hours"] as? String
        if let location = record["location"] as? CLLocation 
        {
            annotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
        }

        self.points.append(annotation)

        DispatchQueue.main.async
        {
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }

        print("recordFetchedBlock: \(record)")
    }

    self.database.add(queryOperation)
}
```